# How to update ListItems in ListView without creating a new Adapter etc

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, listview

I get my data information (JSON-based) through Volley, then map it with GSON to my DataModel. The JSON e.g. contains Arrays which contains others Arrays.
I will present the result of one Array and if i click on a List Item, the Items should change in reference to the next level Array.

I am searching for an generic solution to click through various ListViews without create a new Adapter etc.

```
array1:
   - item
   - item
   - item
   - array2:
      - item
      - item
      - item
      - array3
        - item
        - item
        - item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Just add a new item iten in adapter object and call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

Comment: Do you meant intent?

Comment: no the create a adapter for listview and the adapter object you create for list view just  let us say its adapter . so adapter.add("your value");

Comment: and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [Filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html). Have your adapter implement Filterable, i.e. a method called getFilter() which returns an instance of your filter. The filter itself implements two methods: performFiltering (CharSequence constraint) and publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results).

In your onItemClick method you would then call
    adapter.getFilter.filter(contraint)
where constraint is a CharSequence differentiating between your array levels. In your performFilter method you would put the values of the new array into results.values and the length of the new array into results.count.

And finally the call to adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() would go into your publishResults method.

Answer (score 0):

`OnClick` of `ListItem` you need to add items into the same `ArrayList` you are using for displaying over `ListView`

```
list.add(model(id, name));
```

and then

```
 if(listView.getAdapter()==null){
      adapter=new Adapter(getActivity(),list);
      listView.setAdapter(horizontalListAdapter);
  }
  else{
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
```